# Login Form Using PHP mySQL and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Please look at the code

```
if(count($errors) ==0)
{
    try {
        $obj_user->login();
        $_SESSION['obj_user'] = serialize($obj_user);
        echo "Success";
        header("Location: index.php");
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Invalid or missing username/password";
    }
}
```

The request is coming from login.php. ISSUE

1. My session is not getting set.
2. I want that when my login get succeed, my page moves to index.php

What actually is doing is that it loads the index.php in the div which is placed for ajax response in login.php.

Comment: Have you `session_start()` somewhere? Can we have the `$.ajax()` code as well?

Comment: Thanks, session issue resolved. Now the issue is moving the page to index if login got succeed

Comment: You would need to redirect the user with javascript in the success callback of your `$.ajax();` function

Comment: Edit your question with the snippet of code.

Comment: `function get() {
            $.post("process_login_ajax.php",{uname:frm_login.txt_uname.value, upass:frm_login.txt_pwd.value}, 
            function(resp){
                $('#errors').html(resp);
            });
        }`